# WCF Service calling another one using impersonation

Tags: c#, wcf, impersonation

I'm facing some impersonation issues.

A user (username = myLogin) has to call a WCF service (WebService_A) on a server (server_A). This service will call another WCF service (WebService_B) on a server (server_B).

I'd like WebService_B to get the identity of the initial caller ("myLogin").

The code looks like :

Client :

```
var proxyA = new WebService_A();
var result = proxyA.GetDataFromA();
```

Web Service A :

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetDataFromA()
{
   var winIdentity = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity;
   using (winIdentity.Impersonate())
   {
       using (var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IWebServiceA>("WebService_A"))
       {
           var proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
           var resut = proxy.GetDataFromB().ToList();
       };
   } 
}
```

I've tried this, with the same result

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetDataFromA()
{
   using (var proxy = new WebService_A("*"))
   {
       proxy.ChannelFactory.Credential.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
       var resut = proxy.GetDataFromB().ToList();
   };
}
```

Web Service B :

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetDataFromB()
{
   using (ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
   {
       return WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
   }
}
```

When `GetDataFromB()` is called, I get a `FileLoadException` (`the file or assembly System.IdentityModel.Selectors is not found`)

Comment: it happens inside the function GetDataFromB or on the call

Comment: On the call of GetDataFromB